# Matrix representations for concatenation of general rational functions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-analysis, representation-theory

I read this other question (trying to find it right now) about **Linear Fractional Transformations**,

$$T(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d} \approx \text {( represented by )} \approx M_T = \left[\begin{array}{rr}a&b\\c&d\end{array}\right]$$
In the sense that matrix multiplication of two such matrices perform the function composition:

$$T_2(T_1(z))\approx\text{( represented by )} \approx M_{T_2}M_{T_1}$$

Now to my question: is it possible to do something similar for a general *rational function* ( quotient between two polynomials ): To construct a matrix for:

$$T(z) = \frac{\sum_{z=0}^{N} n_kz^k}{\sum_{z=0}^{N} d_kz^k}$$

which has the same properties?

Comment: Rational functions are not invertible unless they are Mobius transformations. Are you familiar with [*why* Mobius transformations may be represented using matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1989345/motivation-for-mobius-transformation)? (From projective geometry...)

Comment: I think it may have been explained in terms of projective geometry in my one complex variable once upon a time where Mobius transformations were covered somewhat. But sadly I am on the run and don't have access to my old book. Thank you for the update @arctictern.

Comment: @arctictern: Ok they may not be invertible, but not all matrices are either, so it does not contradict the possibility of finding a matrix for them, right?

Comment: The reason matrices represent mobius tranformations does not generalize to rational functions - they are in general too nonlinear (unlike mobius transformations, which are at least projective in nature).

Comment: Okay, that sounds reasonable. But maybe we could do it with a sequence of products instead of just one?